# In railstutorial.com chapter 3 edit Guardfile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in 3.6.2 Automated tests with Guard

tutorial is..

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false do   .   .   .  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
    ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
     "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
     (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                       "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]   end   watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
    (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                       "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")   end   .   .   . end
```

but i don't know how to edit my Guardfile

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'rspec', :version => 2 do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
```

...

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2 do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
```

...

please help me.
just insert do?
but same error..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Listing 3.3.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code%3aguardfile) is just telling you what changes and additions you should make to the default **Guardfile**.  So:

Change the line

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2 do
```

to

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false do
```

and add the rest of the code

```
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
  ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
   "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
   (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                     "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
end
watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
  (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                    "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
end
```

to the end of your **Guardfile**.

Or, you can just copy and paste directly from the [sample_app Github repo's **Guardfile**](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/Guardfile).

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, please click the tick button to accept the answer.

Comment: That's great! If you want to let everyone know that this problem is solved (and share the love around), please consider clicking the green tick button.

Comment: Sorry, by "tick" button, I meant the green "✓" mark below the number.  If you click this, you mark the question as having been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false do

and add code

```
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
  ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
   "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
   (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                     "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
end
watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
  (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                    "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should look if you are doing the latest version of this tutorial

> require 'active_support/inflector'
>
> guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false, cli: '--drb' do
>   watch('config/routes.rb')   # Custom Rails Tutorial specs
>   watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller).rb$}) do |m|
>       ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
>        "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
>        "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
>        (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
>                          "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]   end
>   watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
>       (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
>                         "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")   end
>   watch(%r{^app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb$}) do |m|
>       "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"   end
>
> end
>
> guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env
>   => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do   watch('config/application.rb')   watch('config/environment.rb')   watch('config/environments/test.rb') 
>   watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+.rb$})   watch('Gemfile')
>   watch('Gemfile.lock')   watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
>   watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
>   watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
>   watch(%r{^spec/support/.+.rb$}) end
>
> guard 'rspec' do   watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec.rb$})
>   watch(%r{^lib/(.+).rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
>   watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
>
> # Rails example   watch(%r{^app/(.+).rb$})
>   { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }   watch(%r{^app/(.*)(.erb|.haml)$})
>   { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}*spec.rb" }
>
>   watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)*(controller).rb$})  { |m|
>   ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
>   "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
>   "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
>   watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+).rb$})                  { "spec" }
>   watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
>   watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  {
>   "spec/controllers" }
>
> # Capybara features specs
>   watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*.(erb|haml)$})          { |m|
>   "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
>
> # Turnip features and steps
>   watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+).feature$})
>   watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps.rb$})   { |m|
>   Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' } end